# Create vtk file of ParaView from Mathematica [FEM post-processing]

Tags: finite-element-method, postprocessing

I'm doing FEM in Mathematica and want to visualize the results in Paraview (e.g., create a video of the displacement field). Now I have the element mesh, the displacement and stress fields. How can I convert the data into VTK format as readable by Paraview?

The minimum code is as follows.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

op = {Inactive[
       Div][({{0, (Y ν)/((1 - 2 ν) (1 + ν))}, {Y/(
          2 (1 + ν)), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
       y}] + Inactive[
       Div][({{(Y (1 - ν))/((1 - 2 ν) (1 + ν)), 0}, {0, 
          Y/(2 (1 + ν))}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
       y}], Inactive[
       Div][({{0, Y/(2 (1 + ν))}, {(
          Y ν)/((1 - 2 ν) (1 + ν)), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
         u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
     Inactive[
       Div][({{Y/(2 (1 + ν)), 0}, {0, (
          Y (1 - ν))/((1 - 2 ν) (1 + ν))}}.Inactive[Grad][
         v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}]} /. {Y -> 2.5, ν -> 1/4};

Subscript[Γ, 
  D] = {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0.}, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == 0.}, y == 0]};

b2 = 1;
(*b2=Piecewise[{{1.5x y,y<1},{1.5,y≥1}}];*)

{ufun, vfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == {0, b2}, Subscript[Γ, D]}, {u, 
    v}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]; 
(*∇·σ+Overscript[b, ⇀]=0, given \
Overscript[b, ⇀]={0,-1}, compare the result with that of \
"LE_Example_Single_Step.nb"*)

mesh = ufun["ElementMesh"];
deformedMesh = ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {ufun, vfun}];
Show[{mesh["Wireframe"], 
  deformedMesh[
   "Wireframe"[
    "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
     Directive[EdgeForm[{Thin, Red}], FaceForm[]]]]}]

ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"], Contours -> 50, 
 ContourLines -> False, ImageSize -> 200, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
ContourPlot[vfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"], Contours -> 50, 
 ContourLines -> False, ImageSize -> 200, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: What's the reason you do not want to use Mathematica for the visualization? It might be easier than to write an export for `ElementMesh` and interpolating functions - though not undoable.

Comment: Did you manage to export the data to paraview? I would like to do the same.

Comment: @user21 does MMA 13 now support .vtk file of ParaView in FEM post-processing?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, no there is no export of interpolating functions to vtk; however, in version 13 [VectorDisplacementPlot](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/VectorDisplacementPlot.html) was added. Also check out the [Solid Mechanics tutorial](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/SolidMechanics.html) that has many visualizations ideas.

Comment: @user21 thanks a lot for your support! is it also the case/option that we can (quickly) develop plasticity material models in MMA 13?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, I have done hypoelastic (not hyperelastic!) material models; those are shown in [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xs_Ki_HTJE). But that's not true plasticity. The one think that worries me is the 'quickly' - I don't think any nonlinear material model can be developed quickly ;-)

Comment: @user21 thanks! 'quickly' here could mean that we can add new material models like 'UMAT-Abaqus'.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, the way to do that is like shown in the presentation. This is currently not documented. But if this is what you want to do I can send you a notebook that shows this. Let me know. Or perhaps we could make it a question here.

Comment: @user21 thanks for your support again!  I will first try viscoelastic materials in MMA13.